# PHP infinite loop on two communicating classes

Tags: php, loops, class, memory, size

This is my first time having this problem and I hope that you can give me some explanation or some impetus to solve it.

I wrote this code here:

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar = New Bar();
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = New Foo();
    }
}

$foo = New Foo();
```

This code throwns following error:

`Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)`

How can I let the two classes communicate with each other without getting this error?

### Edit:

As requested, I'll go into a little more detail. As an example, I have written two classes that are forced to communicate with each other, similar to my current project:

```
    class UserStatusController
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->couponController = New CouponController();
        }
        
        private $badStatus = "blocked";
        
        public function hasBadStatus(int $id): bool
        {
            $user = User::where(['id' => $id])->get();
            return $user->status == self::$badStatus ? true : false;
        }
        
        public function actualizeStatus(int $id, string $status): bool
        {
            if ($status == self::$badStatus) {
                
                $this->couponController->deleteCoupon();
                return false;
            }
            
            $user = User::where(['id' => $id])->update(['status' => $status]);
            $this->couponController->createCoupon();

            return true;
        }
    }
    
    class CouponController
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->userStatusController = New UserStatusController();
        }
        
        public function createCoupon(): bool 
        {
            if ($this->userStatusController->hasBadStatus()) { return false; }
            // create coupon ...
        }
        
        public function deleteCoupon(): bool 
        {
            // delete coupon ...
        }
    }
```

Since the two classes each have information that the other class needs, they have to somehow exchange data. In the example above there is an infinity loop.

So the question is, what is the most common way of letting these two classes talk to each other?

Comment: Every time you construct one class it immediately constructs the other, which then makes a new copy of the first class, which then makes a new copy of the second class, and so on forever. Are you wanting each class to maintain a reference to each other?

Comment: Circular references are very often *bad practice*. Does Foo really *need* a reference to Bar? And vice versa? Maybe one does, but the other doesn't? Maybe what you need is a model class which handles communication between the two, or maybe you want to use some interfaces to abstract the communication between the two.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you initiate `New Bar();` in class Foo, and then initiate `New Foo()` in class Bar, which initiates `New Bar()` and so on.

The code below returns `bool(true)` which I presume is what you at trying to achieve.

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public function foo1()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
class Bar
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = New Foo();
    }
}
$foo = New Foo();
var_dump( $foo->foo1() );
```

If you need something else please edit your question and be more specific. On the other hand, if you ammend the code like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public function foo1()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
class Bar
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = New Foo();
        return $this->foo;
    }
}
$foo = New Bar();
var_dump($foo);
```

the result is `object(Bar)#1 (1) { ["foo"]=> object(Foo)#2 (0) { } }`

Also, if the 2 functions are on the same file, you don't need to have another class. If they have to be in separate files, you can write `class bar extends Foo`. There are a lot of OOP courses and free videos explaining classes, functions and so on.

Comment: Please check my added code, i think it's a simple architectural problem. Thank you for your anwer. If there are no further comments, I will close this post and continue to deal with the topic of software architecture.